# Love2d: Creating multiple of the same object from a different file

Tags: lua, love2d

I was wondering if it is possible to create multiple of the same object that is written in a separate file. 
I have two files: main.lua and player.lua.
This is player.lua:

```
    local player = { }
function player:create (x, y, sp)
    self.img = love.graphics.newImage ('images/player.png')
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.speed = sp
end

return player
```

I want to include this file in main.lua. I know I can't use `require "player"` because `require` only allows a file to be loaded once but it doesn't need me to specify a file path. I tried using `dofile()` which actually did exactly what I wanted it to do, however, it does requires me to specify a full file path which I don't want to do.
So this is the part from main.lua:

```
local Player = require "player"
local Player2 = require "player"
-- local Player = dofile("/long/path/to/game/player.lua")
```

If I can't use `require`, is there a way to get the current file directory and use it like this:

```
local Player = dofile(filepath .. "player.lua")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should approach this by changing `create` to a function which actually creates *new* instances of `Player`, instead of modifying the singleton object.

```
-- Player.lua
local Player = {}

function Player:create (x, y, sp)
    self.__index = self

    return setmetatable({
        img = love.graphics.newImage('images/player.png'),
        x = x,
        y = y,
        speed = sp
    }, self)
end

return Player
```

Now you can use `Player:create` to create multiple instances.

```
-- main.lua
local Player = require 'Player'

local player1 = Player:create(10, 10, 5)
local player2 = Player:create(40, 40, 2)
```

---

Consider reading chapter 16 of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html), which covers [Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

Answer (score 0):

that loads the image serveral times... couldnt you just load an image once then call that image in a varable later like so:

```
-- Player.lua
local Player = {}
local img1 = love.graphics.newImage('images/player.png') <-- loaded one time

function Player:create (x, y, sp)
    self.__index = self

    return setmetatable({
        img = img1,    
        x = x,
        y = y,
        speed = sp
    }, self)
end

return Player
```